# 403 Forbidden for jdbc driver from Oracle repository

Tags: java, oracle, gradle, jdbc

I want to download the `odjbc7.jar` at compile time so that I can run all of my tests in Travis CI. I've added a setting in my `gradle.properties` so that it'll only download the jar for building.

Users of my tool will provide the driver themselves so as not to go against Oracles license agreements.

All of the solutions I have found online answer the question by saying to point to a local jar which won't work for my CI build or for others wanting to build the application (I can't distribute the ojdbc jar as part of my repository).

Below is the relevant sections of my `build.gradle`, 
I have the properties *mavenOracleUsername* and *mavenOraclePassword* in my `gradle.properties` (I have checked these are correct on the Oracle single-sign on site) :

```
def oracleUsername = hasProperty('mavenOracleUsername') ? mavenOracleUsername : System.getenv('mavenOracleUsername')
def oraclePassword = hasProperty('mavenOraclePassword') ? mavenOraclePassword : System.getenv('mavenOraclePassword')

repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url "https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content"
//        url "https://maven.oracle.com"
        credentials {
            username "${oracleUsername}"
            password "${oraclePassword}"
        }
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.oracle.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc7', version: '12.1.0.2'
}
```

When I run my build I get the following error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2.
  Required by:
      project :
   > Could not resolve com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

If I change the credentials I get a 401 response and if I change the version of the jar I get a *not found in repository* error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to be to upgrade the version of the driver to `ojdbc8`.

This link helped:

https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides

My `build.gradle` now looks like:

```
def oracleUsername = hasProperty('mavenOracleUsername') ? mavenOracleUsername : System.getenv('mavenOracleUsername')
def oraclePassword = hasProperty('mavenOraclePassword') ? mavenOraclePassword : System.getenv('mavenOraclePassword')

repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url "https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content"
//        url "https://maven.oracle.com"
        credentials {
            username "${oracleUsername}"
            password "${oraclePassword}"
        }
    }
}

...


dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.oracle.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc8', version: '12.2.0.1'
}
```

I have also documented an issue I raised on a tutorial GitHub repository:

https://github.com/robin-a-meade/example-gradle-oracle/issues/1

Edit:
Any issue arose with this dependency, so I had to change to this:

```
compile(group: 'com.oracle.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc8', version: '12.2.0.1') {
    exclude module: 'xmlparserv2'
}
```

For an explanantion of why this is needed, see here this question: [Is "xmlparserv2" from "com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8" (v12.2.0.1) all of a sudden corrupt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610754/is-xmlparserv2-from-com-oracle-jdbcojdbc8-v12-2-0-1-all-of-a-sudden-corru/53024833#53024833)

Comment: This worked! Thank you very very much. All the other solutions wanted me to install Maven, but this one worked with just gradle.