# Oracle ojdbc8 12.2.0.1 Forbidden by Maven

Tags: java, oracle, maven, ojdbc

Oracle ojdbc8 12.2.0.1 **Forbidden** by Maven since December 2017, before that worked well. **What configuration has changed on the Oracle repository (setting.xml)?**

Maven project: https://github.com/sgrillon14/MavenSampleOracleJdbc

Full trace: https://travis-ci.org/sgrillon14/MavenSampleOracleJdbc

Comment: See here for a solution that works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004794/403-forbidden-for-jdbc-driver-from-oracle-repository

Comment: @Ariel, this solution is Gradle but my question is on Maven

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible that the Oracle Maven terms have changed. You may need to re-register on the Oracle Maven site: http://www.oracle.com/webapps/maven/register/license.html
I tried your github script and it worked fine with me:

```
$ mvn clean install --settings test/mvnsettings.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mavensampleoraclejdbc 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ mavensampleoraclejdbc ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/jean/Downloads/MavenOracle/MavenSampleOracleJdbc-master/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mavensampleoraclejdbc ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/jean/Downloads/MavenOracle/MavenSampleOracleJdbc-master/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ mavensampleoraclejdbc ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ mavensampleoraclejdbc ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/jean/Downloads/MavenOracle/MavenSampleOracleJdbc-master/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mavensampleoraclejdbc ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ mavensampleoraclejdbc ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ mavensampleoraclejdbc ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/jean/Downloads/MavenOracle/MavenSampleOracleJdbc-master/target/mavensampleoraclejdbc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ mavensampleoraclejdbc ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/jean/Downloads/MavenOracle/MavenSampleOracleJdbc-master/target/mavensampleoraclejdbc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/jean/.m2/repository/com/github/sgrillon14/mavensampleoraclejdbc/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mavensampleoraclejdbc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/jean/Downloads/MavenOracle/MavenSampleOracleJdbc-master/pom.xml to /Users/jean/.m2/repository/com/github/sgrillon14/mavensampleoraclejdbc/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mavensampleoraclejdbc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.900 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-12T17:06:49+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
wagram:MavenSampleOracleJdbc-master jean$
```

Comment: I reactivated my account (by mail) but the result is wrong. So, I create a new account and i have the same problem. What you check in Oracle account please?

Answer (score 21):

This is from the Maven Central Repository. Please try with these maven settings in your pom file to pull from the Maven Repository. The Group Id is different.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @jnovack If you know how Maven works, no additional context is needed; this answer is self-explanatory.  If you do not, a Maven tutorial is out of scope for an answer to this question.  The answer is fine as is IMO.

Comment: @nasch the answer is fine as is NOW, because it was edited after my post providing the more context that is helpful for long-term value.

Comment: Ah got it - good comment then!

Answer (score 13):

1. Since Oracle JDBC Driver is not in Maven repository,  Download ojdbc8.jar and run the below command.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/cm/Videos/ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

2. Add this dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: do not work wiihout credentials in Maven setting.xml!!

Comment: you can find a sample [here](https://github.com/sgrillon14/MavenSampleOracleJdbc)

Answer (score 5):

Here's the underlying problem

```
Access denied to: https://maven.oracle.com/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden
```

I'm guessing you have the wrong username/password in your `settings.xml`. Try hitting the URL in your browser and enter the username/password. Possibly your credentials have expired? Or maybe you have a different `settings.xml` on travis than your localhost?

Comment: I have this message since December 2017, before that worked well.: Unable to download '4002679'. User 'xxxxxx@hotmail.fr' does not have sufficient privileges to access the content account 'FMWMAVEN/FMWMAVENADMIN'.
Back to previous page

Comment: Guess you need to get a username/password that works. Perhaps your account expired? No idea

Comment: My username/password works on `https://www.oracle.com/index.html` Sign-In

Comment: Ok... but can you then hit `https://maven.oracle.com/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.pom`? If not I'm guessing your user, for whatever reason, no longer has the required priviledges to download the file

Comment: Or maybe oracle have removed the artifact and `ReasonPhrase:Forbidden` is just a poor description? Maybe try the latest version to see if that works?

Comment: 12.2.0.1 is the last version (I think)

Comment: ok... well... whatever the case... you need to get a url, username and password that works before your build will work. Does your company have it's own internal nexus repository? Perhaps you could install it there and reference from there?

Comment: If it worked before an now fails the problem is on server side. I would recommend to ask in the Oracle Forums for assistance, may be the server is just down or something significant has changed.

Comment: This is my original question: `what has Oracle changed in repository configuration since December 2017?`

Comment: No idea... is there a way to seatch the repository at (https://maven.oracle.com)? I don't have a login... if you can find the artifact, you can find the new URL

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have dependency add it otherwise for oracle, replace it with the following code:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
   <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested for downloading ojdbc8.jar from 12.2.0.1. I was able to download without any issues. But, there is a warning. But, the warning is due to the missing *.md5 file in the maven repository. (We are looking into that issue)

**Downloading:** https://maven.oracle.com/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.pom
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected 3626be7f20ea523d9fd6aca576d5aba3f7afb3fe but is f1be766b419370110b86bd088a69c1bfcdca6989 for https://maven.oracle.com/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.pom
**Downloaded:** https://maven.oracle.com/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.pom (7 KB at 0.4 KB/sec)

Comment: This is because Oracle did something quite naughty... they altered the originally published POM without bumping the version number.   That's why you get the checksum validation error when using Maven.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle Maven repository requires you to agree with the terms and conditions of using it. Thus, in order to provide this agreement:

- go to Oracle.com and login
- go to https://maven.oracle.com
- the page shown shows:

  ...
  Directory browsing is not allowed on the Oracle Maven Repository.

  Registration is required to access the Oracle Maven Repository. To register, please visit the **registration site**.
  ...

The link to the "registration site" is actually http://www.oracle.com/webapps/maven/register/license.html

where you have to accept the terms and conditions. This allows you to use the Oracle Maven repository.

For further details on setting up Maven and published drivers, pleaase refer to

https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides

Answer (score 0):

version in the MANIFEST is 12.2.0.1.0 not 12.2.0.1 but still the problem

"Content Server Request Failed
Error Unable to download '(null)'. 'path:/Enterprise Libraries/content/maven/content/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojd‌​bc8-12.2.0.1.pom' does not exist.
"

my credential are OK and got the problem on
https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc6/ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.pom
(the URL you are redirected to when accessing to maven.oracle.com)
too

FYI:
Latest attempt this Sat 6/01/2018 morning: OK, was able to download ojdbc8 POM from a browser.

Comment: I try today with ojd‌​bc8-12.2.0.1.0 => artifact do not exist. I try today with ojd‌​bc8-12.2.0.1 => Access denied to: https://maven.oracle.com/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden

Comment: indeed, random behavior…

Comment: Were you able to download the JDBC driver from oracle maven?

Answer (score 0):

This artifact was moved to:
com.oracle.database.jdbc » ojdbc10