# Failed to load driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context

Tags: spring, oracle

I'm working with Spring for the first time and trying to set it up so that my code can access an Oracle database. I have the following configuration in my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@140.192.30.237:1521:def
    spring.datasource.username=<username>
    spring.datasource.password=<password>
    spring.datasource.driver.class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

My pom.xml contains the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Yet I get the following error and am not sure how to solve it, I"ve found similar ones from searching but none that have solved my problem:

```
Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

    Property: driverclassname
    Value: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
    Reason: Failed to load driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Thanks for any tips to solve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096184/oracle-ojdbc8-12-2-0-1-forbidden-by-maven

Comment: If you are not using multiple data sources then remove mysql-connector-java, spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb, h2, mongo-java-driver and run mvn clean install to install all jars cleanly as seems some jar corrupted then start..

Answer (score 12):

As its mentioned in your error the problem is with your configuration.
Following line,

```
spring.datasource.driver.class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

should change as,

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

> Note that its not **driver.class-name**, instead its **driver-class-name**

Comment: Hm. that seems to work but now I'm being told "Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" through multiple exceptions being thrown. Any idea?

Comment: Its basically the class is not present in your classpath. The same kind of error is discussed here. please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository

Answer (score 1):

```
    Add below dependency and repository in the pom

    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
       </repositories>


Also add the following properties in the application.properties

 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe(SID)
    spring.datasource.username=system
    spring.datasource.password=pw
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same probleme
Add this dependence to POM.xml file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try on the project directory pom.xml file in in command promt or your ide.

mvn clean install

Answer (score 0):

Below dependency to POM should work.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```