# Is "xmlparserv2" from "com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8" (v12.2.0.1) all of a sudden corrupt?

Tags: oracle, maven, gradle

I have an oracle maven dependency in my gradle.build file. Everything was working fine. Then I cleared my cache.

Now this dependency

```
compile('com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1')
```

Gives me this error

```
error: error reading /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.oracle.jdbc/xmlparserv2/12.2.0.1/90c56300a160a184263c45f4d1ffa126216313a1/xmlparserv2-12.2.0.1.jar; error in opening zip file 
error: error reading /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.oracle.jdbc/xmlparserv2/12.2.0.1/90c56300a160a184263c45f4d1ffa126216313a1/xmlparserv2-12.2.0.1.jar; error in opening zip file
```

What is going on? Did Oracle overwrite an existing file with a corrupted version? But more importantly - what do I do now?

Comment: Hi again. Did you solve your issue back in 2018? if so it would be useful to mark one of the as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this (colleague had a version of the jar from June) and the new one is indeed corrupt. Swapped the old jar for the maven downloaded one and it finally compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem in my CI build
The solution was to remove the dependency:

```
compile(group: 'com.oracle.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc8', version: '12.2.0.1') {
    exclude module: 'xmlparserv2'
}
```

P.S I've run into no problems after removing this./